# Finding $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\lfloor \frac{2017 \sin x}{x} \rfloor +\lfloor \frac{2017 \tan x}{x} \rfloor $

Tags: limits, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Finding value of $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\bigg\lfloor \frac{2017 \sin x}{x}\bigg \rfloor +\bigg\lfloor \frac{2017 \tan x}{x}\bigg \rfloor,$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ is floor function of $x$

**Attempt** as we know $\sin x< x < \tan x$

wan,t  be able to go further, could some help me, thanks

Comment: For small values of $x$, $\sin x \approx x$ and $\tan x \approx x$.

Comment: means $\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{x}<1$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\tan x}{x}>1$, but i did not understand what is approx value of theses

Comment: I wonder why wolfram alpha gives 4033 not 4034. Eager to know the answer of this question.

Comment: means one value is $2016$ and other is $2017,$ i did not understand how can i calculate it

Comment: The sin x part will be 2016, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the key is that $\sin x<x<\tan x$ for $x\to0^{+}$, which implies $\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{x}<1<\frac{\tan x}{x}$. Since after division both expressions are even functions, this double inequality is true both as $x\to0^{+}$ and as $x\to0^{-}$. We also know that both $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$, but due to the inequalities, $\sin(x)/x$ approaches $1$ from below, while $\tan(x)/x$ approaches $1$ from above.

Since $\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{x}<1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, for $x$ sufficiently close to $0$ we have:
$$1-\frac{1}{2017}<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1 \implies 2016<\frac{2017\sin x}{x}<2017 \implies \left\lfloor\frac{2017\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor=2016.$$

Similarly, since $\displaystyle \frac{\tan x}{x}>1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$, for $x$ sufficiently close to $0$ we have:
$$1<\frac{\tan x}{x}<1+\frac{1}{2017} \implies 2017<\frac{2017\tan x}{x}<2018 \implies \left\lfloor\frac{2017\tan x}{x}\right\rfloor=2017.$$

Comment: Thanks zipirovich, but i did not understand why $\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{2017}<\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\tan x}{x}>1+\frac{1}{2017},$ explain me

Comment: @DURGESHTIWARI: Because of the limit. Think of the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits. Pick $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2017}$. Then there exists a $\delta>0$ such as as long as $0<|x|<\delta$ (that's the "sufficiently close" part), $|\frac{\sin x}{x}-1|<\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2017}$, or equivalently $1-\frac{1}{2017}<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1+\frac{1}{2017}$. The right-hand side of this double inequality is irrelevant, though, because we know that $\sin(x)/x<1$. So we get that $1-\frac{1}{2017}<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$.

Comment: very nice approach